# Ка сделать подключение сокета единажды

Tags: java

Надо создать сокет 1 раз, что поменять в коде?

```
class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String line = null;
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            strBuilder.append(params[i]);
        }
        String command = strBuilder.toString();

        try {
            // Создаем сокет

            Socket socket=new Socket("192.168.0.102",6666);
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            if(socket.isConnected()) {
                out.writeUTF(command);
                out.flush();
                line = in.readUTF();
                return line.toString();
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Socket not alive!");
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return ex.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вынести подключение к сокету в отдельный класс и реализовать синглтон. Главное не забывать его закрывать когда уже не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вынести объект `Socket socket=new Socket("192.168.0.102",6666);` за пределы повторяющегося кода.

---

я бы сделал так:

```
class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {

    private Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        ...

        try{
            // Создаем сокет
            if (socet == null) {
                socket=new Socket("192.168.0.102",6666);
            }
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            ...
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            return ex.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я нажимаю кнопку и активируется этот метод, не выйдет так сделать.

Comment: вы код покажите весь. По этому отрывку можно посоветовать только вынести за пределы

Comment: код поменял на более открытый.

Comment: @Евгений дописал код в ответ.

Comment: спасибо, но реализовал через закрытие в конце if.